# awk in ssh in su in a command substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, awk, quoting

I am creating a script that will ssh to a host and print all the user accounts and when they will expire.

On a host I can run `awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd` and it will give me a list of all user accounts.

I have added this to a script that should go to a server, create this list and use it to print when it will expie.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in `cat /admin/lists/testlist`
do
  echo $i
  UNAME=`su - admin -c "ssh $i uname"`

  if test "$UNAME" = "Linux"
  then
    LIST=`su - admin -c "ssh $i awk -F':' '{ print $1}' /etc/passwd"`
    for j in $LIST
    do
      echo "$j " ; `su - batch -c "ssh $i sudo chage -l $j | grep Account"`
    done

  else
    echo "Exiting. The OS type is not found."
  fi

  echo "========================================================================"
  echo " "
done

exit 0
```

The issue I am having is when I run the script I get the following error.

```
[admin@testserver bin]$ sudo checkPasswdExpiration.sh
testserver02
awk: cmd. line:1: {
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
========================================================================
```

Why does the awk command not work in this script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first set of quotes is eaten up by the command line for `su`, and the second set by the command line for `ssh`, so that the quoted `{ print $1}` is actually seen as three separate arguments by `awk`. Escape the quotes (*and `$`*, and any other special character you may use):

```
su - admin -c "ssh $i awk -F: \'{ print \$1}\' /etc/passwd"
```

Or:

```
su - admin -c "ssh $i getent passwd" | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```